# From one-dimension-SVR to multi-dimension-SVR (?) using MATLAB/LibSVM

Tags: matlab, libsvm

this is my first post here. I already checked the Thread-Tags but I did not find any answer...

My problem/question is how I can upgrade my SVR from one-dimension- to multi-dimension-regression.
Its more a basic question.
So let me introduce you into this.

First I built a one-dim-SVR using MATLAB/LibSVM recording to an already existing Thread:
[LibSVM and matlab for time series prediction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33738/libsvm-and-matlab-for-time-series-prediction)

```
x = [1:10]'; //full data set
y = [11:11:110]'; //full label set
TrainingSet = x(1:end-3);  //training data for SVR (70%)
TrainingSetLabels = y(1:end-3);  //training labels for SVR (70%)
TestSet = x(8:end);  //test data (30%)
TestSetLabels = [0;0;0]; //test labels 
options = ' -s 3 -t 0 -c 100 -p 0.001 -h 0';
model   = svmtrain(TrainingSetLabels, TrainingSet, options);

[predicted_label, accuracy, decision_values] = ...
    svmpredict(TestSetLabels, TestSet, model);
```

This is a simple code for one-dim-regression. With a data amount of 10 values.
To train the machine it uses the first 7 values with its labels. After this the last
3 values are used for regression.
With this code I get pretty good regression and accuracy.
This works. Fine!

---

Now, I want to simply upgrade this into a multi-dim-regression.
To understand this I want a 2-class-regression.

Lets say each class has also 10 values like the first code above. And the values are the same (from 1 to 10).
The labels are the products of coresponding values like:

1. labels   X1   X2
2. 1        1    1
3. 4        2    2
4. 9        3    3
5. 16       4    4
6. 25       5    5
7. 36       6    6
8. 49       7    7
9. ?        8    8
10. ?        9    9
11. ?        10   10

The questionmarks representing the "unknown labels". (Of course we know them; not the machine)
So I created this code... just by reading the LibSVM-Readme.

```
x = [1:10; 1:10]'; //full data set with two classes
y = [1; 4;9;16;25;36;49;64;81;100]; // full label set
TrainingSet = x(1:end-3, :); //training data set
TrainingSetLabels = y(1:end-3); //training label set
TestSet = x(8:end, :); //test data set
TestSetLabels = [0;0;0]; //test label set
options = ' -s 3 -t 0 -b 1 -c 100 -p 0.001 -h 0';
model   = svmtrain(TrainingSetLabels, TrainingSet, options);
[predicted_label, accuracy, decision_values] = ...
    svmpredict(TestSetLabels, TestSet, model);
```

Here I get no single good regression and accuracy. Of course I used several Kernels. But there was no exceptable change.

So here is my question/problem:
Is my code wrong?
Did I miss something?
Why do I not get better regression?

Please help me to get into this.
Thank you!

Comment: your second dimension (X2) is exactly the same as X1. Why should that give more information and therefore a better model?
I think what you refer to is simply SVR with more than one dimension. multi-class SVR is not a term.

Comment: Hi. Ok. Sorry I obviously mixed things in language. Then of course I need a model with more dimensions. But it is the same question. How can I add this second dimension X2 and get good regression? I tried it with my code.. -- I edited my post so

Comment: Well the problem is that X1 and X2 is the same. What is your goal? (Because obviously you don't have real life data :-)) If you just want to study, I suggest you use a given dataset (http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/_bq9uxn4.html) instead of making up data. If Matlab works similar as R you don't have to do anything special, the method will use all dimensions automatically.

Comment: Hello again :) TY for your help! That X1&2 are the same just for me (to study and to understand it). But of course there is some real data with me. X1 and X2 are the indices of an m-by-n-matrix. This matrix has 100 fields with values. The main goal is to get the function f(X1,X2) of the matrix. So X1 and X2 are representing some different dimensions. -- As I said, the easy values above are just to get a good model.. these are my thougts behind -- @Patronum I don´t get your last sentence...

Comment: Yes, but it won't work if X1 and X2 are the same. At least not better than only using X1.

Comment: Sorry, my last sentence means that there is nothing wrong with your code. The method will take all dimensions into account. Really, the problem is that X1 and X2 are the same.